# Typescript: Type 'string' is not assignable to type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an object

```
export const TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS = Object.freeze({
  TOP: 'top',
  BOTTOM: 'bottom',
  LEFT: 'left',
  RIGHT: 'right',
});
```

And a component:

```
type Props = {
  text?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  placement?: keyof typeof TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS;
};

const Tooltip = ({
  text,
  children,
  placement = TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS.BOTTOM,
}: Props) => (
  <StyleTippy
    content={<TitleContainer>{text}</TitleContainer>}
    placement={placement}
    arrow={true}
  >
    {children}
  </StyleTippy>
);
```

However, Typescript is complaining that I am sending it a string literal

```
src/components/Tooltip.tsx:41:3 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"TOP" | "BOTTOM" | "LEFT" | "RIGHT"'.

41   placement = TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS.BOTTOM,
     ~~~~~~~~~
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do `TOOLTIP_PLACEMENT.BOTTOM` you get its value, which is `bottom` the lowercase string value.
But `keyof typeof TOOLTIP_PLACEMENT` gets you the keys which are the uppercase keys of the object: `BOTTOM | TOP | RIGHT | LEFT`. that are not strings but a union type.
In order to get the value of a key you can define a type for placement like this:
`type Placement = typeof TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS[keyof typeof TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS];`
which returns the value of the selected key.
However this depends on the property `StyleTippy` expects. I would assign it the type `Placement` as defined before.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are all strings just change your props types so that placement is a string.
When you use `TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS.BOTTOM` you are using the value of `bottom` which is a string so that is whats what the placement prop is expecting.

```
type Props = {
  text?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  placement?: string;
};
```